# Do I need to download all API packages in SDK Manager to build apps for all devices?

Tags: android, api, sdk

Do I need to download all API packages in SDK Manager to build apps for devices which have the older software or does the current API package cover them also?

Comment: no you do not need to download them all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SDK Manager - Do you need to install all android platforms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896828/android-sdk-manager-do-you-need-to-install-all-android-platforms)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to download the "Compile SDK" version of the API, and it needs to be the same than the one you defined for your project.